# Every time I remove .limit(25), method in application_helper stops working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently web-scraping for educational purposes ...

I put a limit in the index action in the controller for 25 entries ...

**`entries_controller.rb`**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController


def index
  @entries = Entry.order("created_at DESC").limit(25)
end

def scrape

    RedditScrapper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

Trying to remove it, but every time I remove the `.limit(25)`, it starts saying that my `cat(category)` in `application_helper.rb` is not working ... specifically it says:

```
NoMethodError in Entries#index


undefined method `remove' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the **`application_helper`** file:

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def cat(category)
        category.remove("https://www.reddit.com/r/").gsub(/\/$/, '')
        #category.gsub(/https:\/\/www.reddit.com\/r\/?/, '').gsub(/\/$/, '')
    end

end
```

Why does that happen?

I'm calling the `cat(category)` method in the `index.html.view`

Here is the **`index.html.erb`**:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card-columns">
   <% @entries.reverse.each do |entry| %>
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-title"><b><%= entry.title %></b></p>
        <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
        <p class="card-type"><%= cat(entry.category) %></p>
       </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

To reiterate my question again, why does `cat(categeory)` method stop working every time I remove `.limit(25)` from index action?

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

This is `reddit_scraper.rb` in lib directory

```
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScrapper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      category = entry.css('p.tagline > a.subreddit')[0]['href']
      Entry.create!(title: title, link: link, category: category )
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be there is a `nil` value in one of those categories after 25

Try to use debugger

Comment: is that possible given the fact that validations exist for the presence of both links and titles? Also, I've put up the scrapper code it can be seen that all are scrapped ...

Comment: you were right. I dumped the contents of the db, and raked the scraper again ... and it came out fine without the lime. So yay. Thank you.

Comment: would you know anything about scopes? I have a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800619/how-to-filter-entries-by-category-scopes-or-another-way ... feel free to answer it ... or not =)