# how to filter entries by category ... scopes or another way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I filter my entries via categories?

I am webscraping reddit for educational purposes and only scraping their titles, links, and categories.

Here is the code for it via lib directory:

```
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScraper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      category = entry.css('p.tagline > a.subreddit')[0]['href']
      Entry.create!(title: title, link: link, category: category )
    end
  end

end
```

Trying to filter this in `index.html.erb` but at loss how to.

Decided to try scopes even though I've never written one before.

Here's the scope in `Entry` model

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :link, presence: true
    validates :category, presence: true

    scope :categorization, -> (category) { where category: category }

end
```

Put the scope on the index action in `entries_controller`

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

 
def index
  @entries = Entry.all
  @entries = @entries.categorization
end

def scrape

    RedditScraper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

Receive this error message stating:

```
ArgumentError in EntriesController#index
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

and it's in reference to the scope.

How do I fix this, or filter the entries by category if there's a different way to do it instead of scopes.

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if additional data is needed.

**Sample of Output**

```
LifeProTips

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/

LPT: if you're in a bad mood or something has annoyed you, be as kind as you can to the next 3 people you encounter. By not reacting to the bad mood, as well as helping others, you'll feel miles better.

/r/LifeProTips/comments/5zf0l2/lpt_if_youre_in_a_bad_mood_or_something_has/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a scope here, they are for cleaning up `where` clauses. Just use [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
def index
  @entries = Entry.all.group_by{ |entry| entry.category } 
  # a shorter more ruby way of writing this is:
  # @entries = Entry.all.group_by(&:category)
end
```

which will create a hash like this:

```
{
  "category1" => [Entry,Entry,Entry],
  "category2" => [Entry],
  ...
}
```

then in your view you can

```
<% @entries.each do |category, entries| %>
  <h1><%= category %></h1>
  <% entries.each do |entry| %>
    <p><%= entry.inspect %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Your 2nd problem is not handling duplicates in the scraper:

change:

```
Entry.create!(title: title, link: link, category: category)
```

to:

```
Entry.where(title: title, link: link, category: category).first_or_create
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ... it works sort of ... a bit puzzled that the output keeps repeating itself ... have posted a sample in post above ... any theories?

Comment: also, I was wondering if it was possible have side column with all the clickable categories listed, so when you click on it, it sorts the entries to show those only ... or is that another question post?

Comment: interesting ... I looked at it again ... and it turns out it's not just duplicating it ... it's literally each separate entry in the database ... I guess because I set the scraper for every two minutes, so it keeps repeating it, right? Because even when I tried `uniq` ... still didn't resolve it ... here's the line that I put in index action `@lala = @entries.uniq.group_by(&:category)`

Comment: @user273072545345 i would guess that your scraper does not handle duplicates very well. which is a separate issue with rails validations. - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: add the `entry.id` to the output and come back here

Comment: BlairAnderson, you're asking about entry.id to see if they're unique, right?

Comment: i can confirm that the entries in the database, while duplicates, definitely had their own id.